# Can't run Python script in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, notepad++

I am just starting to write my first Python scripts and everything was fine, until yesterday when I tried to run a Python script in cmd. Usually, I type: cd Desktop, and than file.py. It always worked, but suddenly when I type file.py, it opens up the script in Notepad++ and it doesn't run the program in cmd. I hope that someone can help..

Comment: You don't give us enough details, check the `PATH` environment variable and be sure that the path to `python.exe` is present.

Comment: you could always do ``python file.py``, well in case python.exe is in system path

Comment: This happens because of Windows `file association`. Something happened that caused .py files to be associated with Notepad.exe.

Answer (score 1):

> cd Desktop, and than file.py

Try

```
cd Desktop
```

then

```
python file.py
```

Notice the keyword 'python' before file.py

Answer (score 0):

Guess in your windows env, .py file already being assign to open with notepad++

Right click any .py files, click properties, change the open with to your python executable, eg. C:\python27\python.exe

***OR***

Explicitly specify to run it with python in cmd

```
cd Desktop
python file.py
```